# Yahoo Authentication in Android

Tags: android, yahoo-api

**My Objective** :
Allow the users to login/register via yahoo mail id and then fetch their profile info (using an android device).

**What I have done** :

- I have followed all the steps mentioned here -> https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/
- I am using Webview pop-up for displaying login scren and authorization screen.

**Problem** :

Some times the process is completed without hassle. But most of the times users are getting this error. "**Cycle Prohibited** - Desrciption could not process your request for the document because it would cause an HTTP proxy cycle"

**Note** :

My Problem is not with the consumer or secret keys obtained from yahoo. Because some times the profile info is fetched without any hassles.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated. Also I can provide more info if the above is not suffice.

Comment: do you still have issue or sorted out ?

Comment: the request failed because, maybe, yahoo restricts the number of login requests from particular IP. don't continuously try to login. while developing i did that.

Comment: to answer your question, the problem does not occur anymore. I did nothing special.